# Android XML Content Type Errors after Update

Tags: android, android-layout

After updating (to the just released updates) a problem occurs: I get an Error message **"Unsupported Content Type in Editor"**

The quick error dialog say's that the layout xml is 'illformed'.  Not sure that has anything to do with it (as these all worked before).  If I click the link in the dialog panel and make an association - same problem occurs (even after rebooting Eclipse).

When I expand the layout XML to the full list of errors, the top two errors are:

> org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException:
> Error opening the Android XML editor.
> Is the document an XML file?  at
> com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.createTextEditor(AndroidXmlEditor.java:617)

Any ideas?  Obviously I can't open it to see what the 'illformed' issues are and, ALL these projects worked fine before the update...

**UPDATED**

If you experience the same/similar problem, add to the list at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15003

The problem follows, but **here's a Workaround that worked for me**: Make the association of the XML to the Android Layout Editor via Eclipse prefs - associating them from the problem dialog doesn't appear to work. Then, restart Eclipse. This is a project per project needed change.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue today. I'm assuming that you've done it already - but just in case - a restart of Eclipse made the issue go away for me.

Comment: Thanks - I restarted it several times without luck. Looking at the actual Error in the errors list - the first one is "is this an xml file".  Somehow, a tag indicating it's a layout xml is missing. I can open a bad one (one that has only four lines) using a regular editor and see nothing wrong with the four lines.  Seems to be a BUG!

Comment: I filed a bug report for this.

Comment: After a bit of experimenting, while it's still a bug(in my opinion) to work around this issure, you simply canNOT use the link in the error pop-up to make a file association fix (at least I couldn't).  Must go into Eclipse Pref's > Android and find the xml file type, select Android Layout Editor> and click the Default button (that moves it to the top of the list).  Then, restart eclipse and, it appears to be per project (meaning, one time doesn't fix them all).  You'd think that trying to open the file with the Android Layout Editor (via right clicking it) would also work but, it doesn't.

Comment: Now I don't know why this should make a difference, but let me give you some more details about my issue.  I was getting the exact same error you are I was sure that I had restarted Eclipse so I was puzzled.  I then shut down Eclipse and opened up Motodev (which I had also updated, I use both) to see if it would have the same issue.  Once it opened I attempted to open the same file as in Eclipse.  It was a little slow opening the new layout editor, but it did work.

Comment: I then shut down Motodev, opened Eclipse and it loaded right up.  I chalked it up to coincidence and figure that I maybe had not restarted Eclipse after all, but seeing as a restart isn't fixing your issue you might want to try opening the project in Motodev.

Comment: Thanks.  I updated again (was prompted to update in eclipse again). That made it worse - it locks up eclipse when opening a layout. I rolled back to a good version. Then, as a test, I rolled forward to the update before the crashing one. Of course, I had the same problem but, I discovered that if I: Open a layout, exit the error dialog, close the project, then re-start eclipse, the layout will open. But, this has to be done on each (individual project).

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting here to other users know how to fix this issue. A simple way to get out of the problem for now: rename the XML file you want to see and the Android Builder will recognize the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after updating to latest SDK (Honeycomb). It happened only on existing projects loaded into Eclipse but not in a new project. My solution was to delete the project first (do not delete the project source code) then import the project again, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Open that XML file in another editor and put the following line at the start:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That problem is the result of the newly installed plugin. Uninstall it!